# Initialize a 2x2 matrix in a class default constructor

Tags: c++, class, matrix, default-constructor

I'm trying to create a 2x2 matrix-class in C++ and want to initialize the matrix to an identity matrix through the default constructor. My class is:

```
class Matrix2x2
{
public:
    Matrix2x2();
    void setVal(int row, int col, double newVal);

private:
    double n[2][2];
};

void Matrix2x2::setVal(int row, int col, double newVal)
{
n[row][col] = newVal;
}
```

I've tried a couple of different constructors, but none of them do what I want.

```
Matrix2x2::Matrix2x2(): setVal(0,0,1), setVal(0,1,0), setVal(1,0,0), setVal(1,1,1)
{  }
```

and

```
 Matrix2x2::Matrix2x2(): n[0][0](1), n[0][1](0), n[1][0](0), n[1][1](1)
{  }
```

I realize that it's probably just a simple mistake somewhere, but I can't seem t find it, any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason your not using a real LA library like Boost uBlas or NT2?

Comment: Why the crazy syntax? Why not make it a normal constructor with default values?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array aggregate:

```
class Matrix2x2 {
public:
    Matrix2x2() : n({{3,1},{4,7}}) {
    }
    void setVal(int row, int col, double newVal);
private:
    double n[2][2];
};
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/c39kyN)

Comment: Thanks, but I get:  
Error: only '()' is allowed as initializer for array member "Matrix2x2::n" at the first '{'.
And Error: expected a ';' at the second ',' and the third '}'.

Comment: @Jon What compiler do you use?

Comment: MS Visual C++ 2010 Express. I had to write the initialization in the constructor body for it to work it seems.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11:

```
Matrix2x2::Matrix2x2(): n{{1,0},{0,1}} {}
```

Historically, you could not initialise arrays in the initialiser list, so if you're stuck in the past then you'll have to assign the values in the constructor body:

```
Matrix2x2::Matrix2x2()
{
    n[0][0] = 1;  // or setVal(0,0,1) if you prefer
    n[0][1] = 0;
    n[1][0] = 0;
    n[1][1] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Only thing "working" is the second alternative. However, that gives me another error when compiling:  

1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Matrix2x2::Matrix2x2(void)" (??0Matrix2x2@@QAE@XZ) already defined in functions.obj  
1>d:\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Ov05\Debug\Ov05.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: @Jon: That sounds like you're defining the constructor in a header. Either move the definition into a single source file, or add `inline` to the definition in the header, or move the definition inside the class definition.

Comment: You were absolutely correct! Thank you.
Moved the definition into my functions.cpp file and everything started working. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create a 2x2 matrix-class in C++ and want to initialize the matrix to an identity matrix through the default constructor.

```
//constructor (inside class)
Matrix2x2()
{
    n[0][0] = 1.0;
    n[1][1] = 1.0;
    n[0][1] = 0;
    n[1][0] = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

or like this

```
Matrix2x2::Matrix2x2()
{  
    setVal(0,0,1);
    setVal(0,1,1);
    setVal(1,0,1);
    setVal(1,1,1);
}
```